# Does Jboss 7 support remote jndi lookups from a remote client

Tags: java, jboss, jndi, jboss7.x

I have custom components that are standalone java components that do not run within the Jboss application server. These components need to interface with a HornetQ JMS queue which runs inside of AS7.

Looking at the Jboss AS 7 documentation, there seems to be conflicting information on whether remote JNDI lookup is supported or not.

This JIRA entry seems to provide some information https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1338 but it doesnt explain it well.

I guess my question is, Is it possible to access JMS queues running within the AS 7 application server from an external standalone client via remote JNDI lookup? If it is not possible is there an alternative approach that can be used to get to the JMS queues from an external remote JNDI lookup?

Comment: Both the JIRA issue and the release notes for 7.1 would indicate that remote JNDI lookups are now supported. You will have to test wether you can access other JMS providers through it though (apart from HornetMQ).

Comment: @Perception - Could you point me to where it says that JNDI is supported for non EJB lookups. thanks

Comment: you can do a search for 'JNDI' in the release notes. It's plaintext so I can't link directly to the relevant sections - https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AS710FinalReleaseNotes.

Comment: It does ...
See here [JNDI lookup and property files][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336478/jboss-7-jndi-lookup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [this comment](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1338?focusedCommentId=12664718&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-12664718) (and subsequent ones) I'd say this is supported in AS 7.1.0.Final (and later). The fact that this goes over remoting and no longer over rmi is an implementation detail which you need to cater for in your code.