# JBoss 7: JNDI lookup

Tags: jboss, jndi

after quite a while I made the remote access to a stateless EJB run under JBoss 7.1.1. using Properties object:

```
Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
    "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://localhost:4447");
jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "remote");
jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "remotepwd");
jndiProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);

String lookupString = "//HelloWorld/HelloWorldBean!org.acme.test.HelloWorld";
HelloWorld hw = (HelloWorld) ctx.lookup(lookupString);
System.out.println("Response: "+ hw.sayHello("Hi there"));
```

So **this works fine** but now I want to put the JNDI thing into jndi.properties file but failed, this is how the file looks like:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.ejb.client.naming
java.naming.provider.url=remote://localhost:4447
java.naming.security.principal=remote
java.naming.security.credentials=remotepwd
```

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:,modulename:HelloWorld,distinctname:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@108c175
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:584)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:119)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:136)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104)
at $Proxy0.sayHello(Unknown Source)
at de.brockhaus.test.client.TestClient.main(TestClient.java:35)
```

I already went through several doco but failed, so how does it have to look like then?

Answer (score 7):

OK, so I found the answer myself ...

First you need to have **two** properties files, jndi.properties plus jboss-ejb-client.properties.

jndi.properties:

```
#
# jndi.properties
#
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.ejb.client.naming
java.naming.provider.url=remote://localhost:4447
java.naming.security.principal=remote
java.naming.security.credentials=remotepwd
```

jboss-ejb-client.properties:

```
#
# jboss-ejb-client.properties
#
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port = 4447
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

Having both of them on the classpath will make the code run like a charm even without specifying the properties within the code.

Still confusing is the construction of the lookup string ...

Comment: For construction of lookup string, you may reference here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project. At the starting of jboss server, for remote link, lookup string is normally right after "java:jboss/exported/"