# weblogic equivalent initialContextFactory in JBOSS?

Tags: jboss, weblogic, porting

In web logic ther is intialconextfactory value in web logic  is "**weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory**" what is in JBOSS 7,1.1 final

Answer (score 0):

You will want the following jndi property:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
```

See more at the following links:

[JBoss 7: JNDI lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336478/jboss-7-jndi-lookup)

https://community.jboss.org/thread/213986?start=0&tstart=0

https://community.jboss.org/message/740263